# Has anyone configured SSL with MyBatis?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, mybatis

I am trying to update an old Java application that uses MyBatis to manage its database connection using the Postgres JDBC driver. We need to migrate to a new cloud database that is enforcing SSL and certificate exchange.

I've searched the docs and Googled for hours, but I can't seem to find any methods for getting this done.

Here's a snippet from my MyBatis configuration XML, based on a tip that gave me hope (from https://www.manniwood.com/mybatis_stuff/index.html ):

```
<dataSource type="POOLED">
    <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}" />
    <property name="username" value="${DB_UNAME}" />
    <property name="password" value="${DB_PW}" />
    <property name="driver.sslmode" value="verify-full" />
    <property name="driver.ssl" value="true" />
    <property name="driver.sslrootcert" value="${DB_CERT_PATH}" />
```

But I am still getting errors along the lines of:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host *.*.*.* ...
```

Does anyone know how to pass the correct parameters into the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding param ssl=true in the database URL

sslfactory : If you don't want to validate the server's certificate but is less secure

jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

For more details, you can check out https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html